# JavaNIO: check File lock created by a root-user from a process running under a normal user?

Tags: java, permissions, locking, nio

I have two processes which I am to synchronize.

Process A is running as root and creates a Reentrant-Lock on a specific file.
Process B is running under a "normal" user and should wait for the lock being releases by process A.

I tried many ways but cannot get it working because of wrong file permissions.
Here is the code:
(removed the in-VM-synchronisation-stuff):

Lock:

```
FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(pFile, "rw").getChannel();
lock = channel.tryLock();
```

hasLock:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(pFile, "rw");
FileChannel channel = file.getChannel();
FileLock lock = channel.tryLock();
if (lock == null) {
 return true;
}
lock.release();
```

The problem I have is that the lock gets created as:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 May  7 21:42 lockfile.lock
```

if I try to check the lock (by process B running as normal user) I get a

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: _lockfile_ (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:212)
```

I tried to umask the directory to all g=rwx,o=rwx but this seems to be ignored. I tried to create the file first, setWritable(true, false) but this seems to be resetted. I did not get any method to work. I tried to use mode "r" instead of "rw" in hasLock but this leads to a ChannelNotWritableException.

So the main question is: how can I influence the permissions of the created lockfile?

Does anyone has some suggestions?

Regards Michael

Comment: What I have done in the past is avoid the need for locks by having an index file for all the records in the data file. This allow concurrent access between processes (provided you only have one writer)

Comment: I do not need to write anything. I just have the need to check if the other process is still running (holding the lock). For some "wait until finished"-method. I am in a stateless webservice which has to overlive process-deads starting other disconnected processes. I can guess the filename as this is constructable out of the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got a solution:

The way of first creating the file was the correct one. The mistake I made was that I set the permissions before file creation (expecting that the permissions are stored in the file object and used on creation). I have to first create the file, then set the permissions to all and then lock it:

```
file.createNewFile();
file.setWritable(true, false);
FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
channel.tryLock()
```

the lockfile is now created with worlwide-writable (this may be a security issue but actually there is no problem visible as the file does not contain any content.

Thanks to everyone helping me to find a solution!

Regards Michael

Answer (score 3):

You are up against the `umask` of the root process, which masks the "rw" you supplied when creating the file to deny write access to `group` and `others`. There is nothing you can do about this except change the root's `umask`, which is a seriously terrible idea for security reasons.

You should look into having the lock file exist permanently, or, as Peter suggests, using a file that is already part of your application as the lock file.

Comment: Do I understand it right, that additionally to the umask of the directory the process itself has also a umask and this is "downgrading" the permissions? Indeed changing the roots umask is not an option.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions so far. To clarify the problem: Process B is a webservice which starts Process A (as root using sudo). Process A returns an identifier (via Sysout) which is also the name of the lock file. The webservice returns this identifier to the caller. By another method the caller should be able to check if the process A has finished or not (or wait until finish). This is what the lock is for. Process A may be running several times in parallel (with differend identifiers) So I cannot use an already existing file :-(

Comment: @user1380578 (1) You shouldn't be starting processes as root at all. (2) You have Process.waitFor() and Process.exitValue(): why do you need a lock file at all?

Comment: I need to start process A as root (as it does changes to the system only root is allowed to) but I don't want the webservice running as root (as you stated too). The webservice calling this is stateless (and should be for several reasons) so the process object is lost between calls. The lockfile is used to get the state back. File is locked = process still running, File absent = process finished (status is written an infofile also based on identifier). InfoFile present = process finished, Lockfile is present and not locked and no infofile = process died and so on.

Comment: @user So why can't you call the APIs I mentioned?

Comment: I cannot call the apis because I do not have the Process-instance needed for that... I just have the identifier...

Comment: @user1380578 Why is that? How does process B start process A?

Comment: process B starts process A using Runtime.Exec and sudo. The resulting process object is forgotten (and the process is disconnected from process B in order to allow process B to die).

Comment: @user1380578 Well that's the problem right there. If you retain the Process object you can wait for it, or see if it's still running, and you don't need this lock file at all. *Much* more reliable.